# Yammer authentication only javascript code

Tags: javascript, yammer

In my web application i add a Yammer frame. 
This frame contains a yammer interface login and i dont have to use it.
I must to login to yammer  using only javascript code  ( i have password and login)

Is it possible?

Comment: [Did you check the documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/js-sdk)?

Comment: I did not find.